# Как избавиться от прокрутки к началу документа, при выполнении javascript?

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на изображение, расположенное внизу страницы, происходит прокрутка к началу документа.

Изображение:

```
<label for="option-value-1" class="radio_opt25">
  <span class="radio_opt25" style="background:url(1.jpg) no-repeat;"></span>
</label>
```

JavaScript, обрабатывающий нажатие:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".radio_opt25").first().addClass('radioOn25');
    $(".radio_opt25").click(function(){
      $(".radio_opt25").removeClass("radioOn25");
      $(this).addClass("radioOn25");
    });
  })
</script>
```

Как избавиться от перескакивания к началу страницы при нажатии на картинку?
Смотрел в интернете: советуют ставить `return false;`, но тогда не работает скрипт. Что делать?

Comment: `$(".radio_opt25").click(function(){
   $(".radio_opt25").removeClass("radioOn25");
   $(this).addClass("radioOn25");
  });`

------------------

Только не бейте, я просто спросить! Кто понимает логику здесь происходящего? O_o

Comment: Поддерживаю...

Comment: На странице есть опции для товара, сделанные через type="radio". Каждая опция оформлена ввиде картинки, при нажатии на которую, все присвоенные ранее стили для других опций, с таким же классом - удаляются. После стиль присваевается выбранной опции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, всем спасибо! Особенно Palmervan, который натолкнул на решение. Вопрос решен. При объяснении алгоритма работы скрипта, в уме представлял структуру опций и стилей, и вспомнил, что для радио кнопок, которые я прятал за границами страницы установлен стиль top:-9999px; - это и было причиной скачка вверх.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".radio_opt25").first().addClass('radioOn25');
  $(".radio_opt25").click(function(){
   $(".radio_opt25").removeClass("radioOn25");
   $(this).addClass("radioOn25");
   return false;
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Смотрел в интернете, советуют ставить return false; - но тогда не работает скрипт.
Так что этот вариант не подходит.
Или может как-то иначе присваивать стиль для выбранной опции?

Comment: а я так и не понял для чего вам .ready ?
И почему не работает скрипт, когда return срабатывает после того как скрипт завершит свое выполнение.
Я в JS не особо хорошо разбираюсь, но думаю у вас просто тут все в кучу намучено, а правильнее будет отделить .ready и .click